# Typescript instance of a class in variable

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to create in TypeScript a function that takes a class as an argument (not an instance but the class itself) and returns an instance of that class, but can't find an effective way to do it.

Code example below:

```
public getService<T extends new (appInstances: AppInstances) => Y, Y extends AbstractService>(serviceClass: T) {
    const service = this.services.find(
      (service) => (service as unknown) instanceof serviceClass
    );
    if (!service) {
      throw new Error(
        'instance of service ' + serviceClass.name + ' not found'
      );
    }
    return (service as unknown) as Y;
}

// type here is any and should be CommandInteractionService
const commandInteractionService = this.getAppInstances().serviceManager.getService(CommandInteractionService);
```

Is there a proper way to achieve this, or is there a workaround?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**edit**

I just found the solution, I am posting it here since it wasn't easy to find. Hoping that future desperate souls find this useful.

```
public getService<T extends new (...args: ConstructorParameters<typeof AbstractService>) => AbstractService>(serviceClass: T): InstanceType<T> {
  const service = this.services.find(
    (service) => service instanceof serviceClass,
  );
  if (!service || serviceClass === AbstractService) {
    throw new Error(
      'instance of service ' + serviceClass.name + ' not found',
    );
  }
  return service as InstanceType<T>;
}
```

You can find documentation about [InstanceType](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#instancetypetype) and [ConstructorParameters](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#constructorparameterstype) on the official TypeScript documentation https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html

Comment: Rather post your solution fully in this answer, instead of in an edit to the question.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

something like this?

```
public getService<T extends new (...args: any[]) => Y, Y>(serviceClass: T): Y {
  const service = this.services.find((service) => service instanceof serviceClass);
  if (!service) {
    throw new Error('Instance of service ' + serviceClass.name + ' not found');
  }
  return service as Y;
}
```

Comment: Yeah but without using `any` as it is bad practice. I found a pretty good solutions using `ConstructorParameters` and `InstanceType` (more details in the edit of my question)

Comment: @leopoldhub if you made a solution that is undoubtly better and different then existing one, post is as answer with explanation

Comment: @Dimava thanks, I forgot... (edit: I cant before 2 days :/)